# How to change the class of a coulmn in dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, type-conversion

I have the Zipcode as a column in a dataframe in below format
19678.0
I would like to convert that into int64
19678
When I am trying to run the below code,

```
call_df['zip']=int(call_df['zip'])
```

It Says
TypeError: cannot convert the series to

Can some one help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for [`astype()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
call_df['zip'] = call_df['zip'].astype(int)
```

Or if you want to specifically cast to int64, use:

```
call_df['zip'] = call_df['zip'].astype('int64')
```

Comment: I have tried the above ,it converted the column to int but still says:  

SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: That warning is not related to the issue of type conversion. Most likely you assigned a slice of some other DataFrame to `call_df` when you created it. You can likely silence the warning by chaining `.copy()` to the end of whatever statement you used to create `call_df` in the first place, but it would be better to have a more detailed read on this warning here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas